# Angular jquery functions are not working in website

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap in an angular app. But there are functions not working for example navbar toggle button is not opening the menu.  So this is the problem in jquery right?

Here is my code

```
 <!-- Navbar -->   
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" >

        <div class="container-fluid">

              <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/img/logo.png"></a>

              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>

              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Team</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Connect</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
<!-- Navbar End -->
```

Also, I already have added jquery and popper.js in angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Already follow all steps like

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

Comment: Please create stackblitz

Comment: @Çağrı updated my question issue is not in code seems like jquery is not working in my project.

Comment: My suggestion: use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). It is an Angular implementation of the Bootstrap code, which doesn't need jQuery.